# Displaying byte array as an image in a JSP

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet that I've designated as the welcome page for my Java Web Application. In the Servlets doGet method, I retrieve a list of Product objects from the database. The Product object is composed of: an ID, Name, Description, and Image(byte[]).

I then add the list of Products to the request as an attribute, and forward to a JSP where I want to display all of the products(in a table). Displaying the properties like name, id, and description are easy.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to display the image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to base 64 encode the image data and generate a data url which look like this:

`data:image/png;base64,21fe8w4r7qwe/f4sd68f4/er41we5f1sd/1a3/13dfvd21`

Something like this code would do the trick:

```
String url = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encode(bytes);
```

then use that url as your image `src`.

Comment: So if the image is a jpg I just use 'image/jpg'?

Comment: That is exactly what you do.

Comment: Ok, and as far as putting it in the database, I have to base64 encode the byte array first, right, in order for the base64 encode to work when I get it out?

Comment: you can base 64 encode before you put it in or after you get it out. there are ups and downs. if you encode before putting it in you take up slightly more memory than the original image. if you encode it after getting it out you sacrifice performance/speed because you have to do it for every retrieval.

Comment: Ok, so I don't necessarily have to encode it before I put it in? I'm asking because I ran the application, and I'm not seeing any image displayed, nor am I getting an error. So I thought that maybe it had something to do with the encoding. I definitely see the blob in the database, so it's there, just a matter of getting it back out.